# Add IP address to lease list on SBS 2003

Tags: dhcp, windows-sbs-2003

I've deleted an IP address by mistake from the DHCP Address Leases list on Small Business Server. Is there a way to get these back or restore them?  I've tried, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, leases are created when a device requests them.

You can go to the PC that owned the lease and type:

```
ipconfig /renew
```

And this should recreate the lease, or you can add a reservation if you know the mac address of the computer.

I thank that these would be your only options.